# Partitioning Table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a long vector array in the following format:

```
{{{{x1,y1,z1,{a,b,c}},{x1,y1,z2,{d,e,f}},...},{{x1,y2,z1,{g,h,i}},{x1,y2,z2,   
{g,h,i}},...},...},{{{x2,y1,z1,{j,k,l}},{x2,y2,z1,{m,n,o}},...},{{x2,y2,z1,   
{p,r,s}},{x1,y2,z2,{t,u,v}},...},...}}
```

I need to add brackets to the first three terms {xi,yi,zi} of every {xi,yi,zi,{a,b,c}}, but I couldn't figure it out myself using

```
Partition
```

Thank you.

Comment: `ArrayReshape[t, Join[Most@Dimensions@t, {2, 3}]]]` where `t` is the target...

Comment: list /. {x1_,y1_,z1_,{a_,b_,c_}}:>{{x1,y1,z1},{a,b,c}}

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Yes, I took OP "long" as implying performance mattered, invoking pattern matcher costs 50-100% performance hit vs reshape... +1 on cmnt though!

Comment: @ciao Could you post that as an answer or vote to close?. Otherwise this will be kept on the unanswered queue

Comment: @belisariusisforth done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment as answer, per request:

```
ArrayReshape[t, Join[Most@Dimensions@t, {2, 3}]]]
```

where *t* is the target.